# Using matlab to compare 2 excel files

Tags: matlab

I want to build a script to compare 2 excel charts to see if there are any changes and that it will show me the difference.

How do I even start?

I tried searching google, but no conclusive answer about this.
I only found a script that does that but only counts how many differences it found by chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving such tasks can be achieved by splitting the problem into smaller ones, which are easier to solve by themselves.
Such a task as the one you described would involve the following steps:

1. Read in the two files
2. Iterate through the elements of the two files
3. Compare the elements to each other

Once you have divided the problem into smaller parts, it also becomes easier to search how the individual steps are done. E.g. a search of "Matlab read excel file" should point you directly to the relevant documentation page.